# How to disable the online Authenticode check everytime you open an EXE?

Tags: windows-7, security, performance, download

Every time you open an EXE file that you've downloaded, Windows 7 checks online if the EXE is signed. Is there a way to disable this?

It takes around five seconds to test if it's okay, and then it shows me this silly warning. Then I click OK, and finally the EXE actually starts!

[image]

Comment: It shouldn't always go online and check.  Many of the popular certifications are already downloaded on your machine, including Microsoft.

Comment: @surfasb: Windows already has the root certificates, but it checks online whether the publisher's certificate has been revoked or not (using OCSP).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a unsafe way to do this:

Go control-panel -> internet options -> security -> custiom level... -> "Launching applications and unsafe files" set that one to enable.

In firefox you can manually turn it off by changing the "browser.download.manager.scanWhenDone" value in your about:config from true to false.

Answer (score 2):

On a per EXE basis, right click the EXE file and choose Properties.  On the bottom of the General tab you should see a button 'unblock', click it and you won't be asked for that file again.

[image]